# Tkinter Button with an If statement

Tags: button, python-3.x, tkinter, conditional-statements

This is my first Python program, and I think I have the if statement correct, I may or may not, I don't know.  What I want to do is, when a Tkinter button is clicked, I want the function which is called to check which image is being displayed ON the button, and then change its image accordingly.

Here's my code for the function:

```
def update_binary_text(first,second):
    if buttonList[first][second]["image"] == photo:
        buttonList[first][second]["image"] = photo1
```

Here's the for loop [2d list of buttons] with the command:

```
for i in range (0,number):
        buttonList.append([])
        for j in range(0,number):
            print(i,j)
            buttonList[i].append(Button(game, borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0, image=photo,command = lambda i=i, j=j: update_binary_text(i,j)))
            buttonList[i][j].grid(row=i*20,column=j*20)
```

The problem is, when I run this, it opens up fine, but when I click all the buttons, nothing happens. If I take out the if statement and just put the assignment, it will work, but I need to check which image is displayed first.
Does anyone have a solution?

---

I just ran into another issue. The solution that I received earlier worked just fine, and changes the image, but only on the first click. After that, it will never change again.

Here is the code:

```
def update_binary_text(first,second):
        #print("Called")
        if buttonList[first][second].image == photo:
                buttonList[first][second]["image"] = photo0
        elif buttonList[first][second].image == photo0:
                buttonList[first][second]["image"] = photo1
```

What happens is, when I click any button for the first time, it will change from a blank button to a  button with an image on it, when I click it again it should change its image, but it doesn't. If anyone wanted to see here's the statements to initialize `photo`, `photo0`, and `photo1`:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file ="blank.gif")
photo0 = PhotoImage(file="0.gif")
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the type of `photo`, but if you use it as an option of Button it cannot be a string. The problem is that `buttonList[first][second]["image"]` returns a string, not the object you use it in the constructor.

A quick solution could be add a `_photo` reference to each Button widget, and then use it to compare with `photo` in the if statement:

```
def update_binary_text(first,second):
    if buttonList[first][second]._photo == photo:
        buttonList[first][second]["image"] = photo1

# ...

def create_button(i, j):
    button = Button(game, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, image=photo,
                    command = lambda i=i, j=j: update_binary_text(i,j))
    button._photo = photo
    return button

buttonList = [[create_button(i, j) for j in range(number)] for i in range(number)]
```

Comment: Thank you sir!!  i tried it with ._photo, and no luck, instead i tried button.image, which ended up working.  Thanks!

Comment: @vap Yes, that is because you have also to implement the other way around too (an if statement where if `.photo == photo1`, the `image` option is set to `photo`).

Comment: Oh!  Now I see why that is.  Thanks again!